# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'isAdmin' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'isAdmin' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (user, user123@gmail.com, $2y$10$hL36LXvdO/0m6PcAtZ1Zvurr5fg6HYX/v9hFTQLPBjYMlWpc3Fkv., 2020-04-18 13:25:15, 2020-04-18 13:25:15))

I can't put data when i click button register

file register.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register')}}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What does your register controller look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happens because Because your isAdmin column is not nullable & when you add a new user data, you don't give any value for isAdmin Column...Here you have Two Solution either in your migration or when you create a user then give it's value either 0 or 1..
Or add a new migration where make this column nullable or set it a default value for this..

```
$table->boolean('isAdmin')->nullable();
```

Or set a default value

```
$table->boolean('isAdmin')->default(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make your `isAdmin` field `nullable` or set default value:

```
$table->integer('isAdmin')->nullable();
```

or,

```
$table->integer('isAdmin')->default(0);
```